# Persisting layer tree between QGIS instances using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

I have been working on a PyQGIS project for a bit, and I have been using `QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer` to add layers to the map.

However, now I need to add layers to my canvas and legend in specific groups, so I changed my logic for adding layers to the map to use the underlying `QgsLayerTree` object to add groups and add layers to those groups. I got it working, but it also introduced a new problem:

Whenever I add a layer to the map within a layer group using the new logic, the layer is not available whenever QGIS is restarted. The `QgsLayerTreeLayer` instances of the layers are still available, but it looks like they can't resolve their references to their source or other metadata. From what I can tell, it looks like they only have access to the layer ID.

How do I persist the layer tree between QGIS sessions? Or is there another way to implement adding layers within groups that would avoid this problem?

---

#### Adding Layers to Map

```
layer = QgsRasterLayer(...)
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
group = root.insertGroup('Layers')
group.insertLayer(0, layer)
```

#### Reading Layers after QGIS Restart

```
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
layer_tree_layers = root.findLayers()  # Returns list of QgsLayerTreeLayer objects

map_layers = []

for lyr in layer_tree_layers:
    map_layer = lyr.layer()  # Once QGIS has restarted, returns None!
    map_layers.append(map_layer)
```

---

I saw that in the [QGIS API Documentation](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayerTreeLayer.html#ac7c463e2587b85cb6ca6f1de4b25d18a), it noted that the `QgsLayerTreeLayer.layer()` may return None/nullptr "...in the case of a layer node representing a layer which has not yet been fully loaded into a project, or a layer node representing a layer with an invalid data source...."

So why does my QGIS workspace persist normal map layers between instances, but not `QgsLayerTreeLayers` that were added to the map programmatically or is there an error in my logic that is causing this?

*Note: The layers that I am loading into the map are QgsRasterLayers that have been read from geopackage tables. Didn't think it had anything to do with this because I am instantiating the layer objects from the source in the same way as I would any other layers. But just thought I'd mention it.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to add the layer objects (and transfer their ownership) to the project. You can add the layer objects to the project first **without** adding them to the legend. The methods `addMapLayer()` and `addMapLayers()` both have a boolean parameter `addToLegend` which defaults to True. By passing False as the second argument, the layers will be added to the project but not the legend. You can then insert your group & layer nodes at the desired location in the layer tree.

For example:

```
layer_1 = QgsRasterLayer('path\\to\\layer_1', 'Raster_A')
layer_2 = QgsRasterLayer('path\\to\\layer_2', 'Raster_B')
QgsProject().instance().addMapLayers([layer_1, layer_2], False) # 2nd argument addToLegend=False
root = QgsProject().instance().layerTreeRoot()
group = root.insertGroup(0, 'Layers')
group.insertLayer(0, layer_1)
group.insertLayer(1, layer_2)
```